# regular expression for @import css tag for all cases

Tags: javascript, css, regex

**hello everyone,
I am doing some work with webpage source code. i need the regular expression for all possible syntax of importing .css file. for example-

```
1.@import url("a.css");
2.@import url('a.css');
3.@import url ("a.css");
4.@import url ('a.css');
5.@import "a.css";
6.@import 'a.css';  etc.
```

i want one regular expression for all cases.please help.**

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far? You can try to write a regular expression for every line and then use "|" to try all of them as in (r1|r2|r3)

Comment: yes i have tried many regular expression but not any of them giving me the the output which i exactly want. some of my expressions are-

Comment: url\\(*\"(.*)\"*\\)||url\\((.*)\\)||@import '(.*)'||@import \"(.*)\"                                    "@import\\s+(url\\(|\\((css)\\))?\\s*(\"|')(.+)\\s*(\"|')(\\))"

Answer (score 3):

I would use the following :

```
@import.*?["']([^"']+)["'].*?;
```

`@import.*?["']` matches the start of the line until a quote or double-quote is opened.
`([^"']+)` matches everything that comes before a quote or double-quote (the url), grouping it.
`["'].*?;` matches the end of the line.

Showcased on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lC1hO3/2).

Comment: but it is not considering ech and every case

Comment: your pattern is not giving answer. i have tried on every string mentioned in question. as it does not include space condition

Comment: What do you call "space condition"? Have you consulted my link? Do you know about negated classes?

Comment: sorry sir, i was wrong . this pattern is working. i took some strings in file and it is working. but i don't know why it is not working on Strings taken in code.

Comment: Also I just saw your comment on the other answer. Don't you think it would have been important to specify that you needed to group the url for replacement on your question?

Comment: I've changed my answer to add url grouping.

Comment: sir but grouping was also done by your last answer too. what is the difference between these two answer given by you.

Comment: My previous answer matched the whole line, but did not make it possible to retrieve the url without additional code : it was the whole line or nothing. Now you can just call `matcher.group(1)` and you'll get the url only. If you look at the newest regex101 you will see it highlights the groups, displaying `a.css` in green on each line.

Comment: you're welcome ! You didn't specify how you wanted to do your replacement btw, there might be other regex tricks I could explain if you gave that info

Comment: yes sir....can you tell me sir, from where i can strong my regex pattern skill. as i am little weak in that.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a good source. Start with their [quickstart](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) and continue with their [java doc](http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html) if it's your language of choice.

Comment: I don't know, looks like it's [working for me](https://regex101.com/r/wZ9xX9/1). I had to escape the `/` for the pattern not to break the javascript standard notation, maybe is that your problem?

Comment: Btw if you're going to parse a lot of html, please for your own sake install and get used to an html parser, you'll be much more efficient in no time.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the previous question, which itself has nothing to do with the answer we're commenting on (which hasn't even been approved regardless of the work provided). I'm not your own personal regex tester, you should ask a new independent question when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

like this:

```js
const re = /(?:@import)\s(?:url\()?\s?["\'](.*?)["\']\s?\)?(?:[^;]*);?/gi;

const s='@import url("fineprint.css") print; @import url("bluish.css") projection, tv; @import \'custom.css\'; @import url("chrome://communicator/skin/"); @import "common.css" screen, projection; @import url(\'landscape.css\') screen and (orientation:landscape);';

s.replace(re, (match, g1) => console.log(match, g1));
```

Answer (score 1):

This expression works for all legal URLs, also those that include quotes, double quotes, semicolons etc. Matches both import statements on single lines and inline statements (e.g. in minified CSS).

One thing to watch out for is that this can have a higher memory consumption because it uses capture groups to match quote pairs. Be careful using this on very large files.

```regex
/@import\s*(?:(['"])?(?:\\\1|.)*\1.*|url\(\s*(?:(['"])?(?:\\\2|.)*\2|(?:\\[\)\'\"]|[^'")])*)\s*\).*);/gUi
```

Test cases: https://regex101.com/r/X6B10k/1

Comment: underrated answer

Answer (score 0):

This is untested:

```
/^@import\s(url\s?\((["'])(.*?)\2|(["']).*?\4);
```

The answer will be in \4

But perhaps merely matching `^@import` is good enough? Do you need to extract the filename?

Comment: yes i need to extract filename and change its path.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to improve accepted regex:

```
@import.*?["']?([^"']+?)["']?.*?;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/@import[^u\"\']+(url[^\(]*\()?(|'|\")(\"|\')([^\"\']+)\.css/gi
```